# CakePHP Config File

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I was wondering is there a way i can set up the config where i can have two database entries that work when the environment is Local and when on Server.

I had come across a solution long time back on doing the switch through the code. Not able to find it now. How do you guys do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a config class which does exactly that:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/08/17/development-vs-productive-setup

Recently I rewrote it for 2.0 as a plugin version.
It now takes care of test environments and cuts down the number of lines of configuration you will have to write:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/25/dynamic-database-switching/

Comment: Thanks Mark :) the above answer i have put up also works. any idea why your method is better ?

Comment: its not about better. mine does a few extra things, has a cleaner approach on this (DRY) as described in the blog post. it also works with CLI (using `path` array). but if your solution works for you, why not.

Answer (score 5):

I have a setup with local config files. I add the following lines at the bottom of app/config/core.php:

```
if(file_exists(ROOT.'/app/config/core.local.php')) {
    include_once(ROOT.'/app/config/core.local.php');
}
```

In core.local.php I can override all the settings that differ on the local machine. The same goes for database.php.

Answer (score 1):

I think it based on IP 
    at local environment IP is 127.0.0.1
and at live environment IP is never 127.0.0.1

My view

Thanks

check with the lib/Cake/Utility/String.php see the function named 
public static function uuid()

cheers

Thanks again

Comment: yes it works some what similar.. damn google cant find me that blog post :P

Comment: check with the lib/Cake/Utility/String.php see the function named 
public static function uuid()

cheers

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );

    public $live = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'db.HOST.net',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );

    public function __construct(){
        if (isset($_SERVER) && isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
            if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'localhost') === false) {
                $this->default  = $this->live;
            }       
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you tried bake with that? I used it before, maybe 1.2 and bake did not work. Also behind a load balancer your SERVER_NAME will be localhost by default, not a good solution imo.